# How do I mock the HttpRequest on an "azure function"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, mocking, azure-functions

I have a function with an Http trigger

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,"post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
```

I want to mock the req. I have manage to do so just fine like this

```
private static Mock<HttpRequest> CreateMockRequest(object body)
{            
    using var memoryStream= new MemoryStream();
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
 
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
 
    writer .Write(json);
    writer .Flush();
 
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
 
    var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Body).Returns(memoryStream);
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.ContentType).Returns("application/json");

    return mockRequest;
}
```

body, in the above code is just some json. I am then using this code to deserialize this the json stuffed in the body of the mockRequest

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseBody<T>> GetBodyAsync<T>(this HttpRequest req)
    using var stream = new StreamReader(req.Body);
    var bodyString = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();
...
}
```

The bodyString is not valid json here because there seems to be escaping of the quotes in the json e.g.
Original Json = `{"x": "somexvalue"}`
the value coming back = `{\"x\": \"somexvalue\"`

Before you say that this is just visual studio debug inspector, it is not. I have checked. It seems the `StreamWriter` is doing this or the `StreamReader` is.

The obvious solution was to just strip the \ out of the resulting json but this feels so wrong and work arroundy. Is there a way to fix this without having to change my function.

Comment: I would expect that code to fail to compile with [Unrecognized escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1009) because of `"application\json"`, as that uses neither "\\" or the @-quoted string literal format.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#c-in-visual-studio

Comment: @YegorAndrosov I have already read that. The fake HttpRequest is only for query strings. Nothing in that documentation to do with the body

Comment: it shows access to request. yes, it shows query only, but body is stored inside `context.Request.Body`, write any stream to it.

Comment: @YegorAndrosov that is exactly what he is doing and is where the problem lies.;

Comment: @ColinM I am suggesting to use standard tools described in article I provided link to, and not `Mock` library.

Comment: Ah, in that case I agree. `StreamWriter` is likely the culprit here, however using `DefaultHttpContext` helps significantly because mocking a `HttpContext` for a request typically requires a lot of setup. Some types defined on `HttpContext` can't be simply mocked.

Comment: Yes, I agree @ColinM. I have changed the code to us DefaultHttpContext now. Gonna have to keep fighting this stream for a bit longer :'(

Comment: @ColinM You were actually on the right line. I have just posted a working version below based on your original comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the issue is with the `StreamWritter`. The way around it is just to not use the `StreamWritter`. @ColinM was on the right line. This is the way to mock the body

```
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

    var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var request = context.Request;
    request.Body = memoryStream;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    return request;
```

Comment: Funnily enough I actually deleted my comment because I tested the code in both scenarios and it worked fine for me. So I'm not sure that `StreamWriter` was the culprit.

Comment: Where does `DefaultHttpContext` come from?